# How to access other files from mod_wsgi on OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift, mod-wsgi

Let's say I have the following two files:

#### main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friendly Testing!</title>
    %(HEAD)
</head>
<body>
    %(HEADING)
    Hi! This is just a friendly person being a friendly tester!
</body>
</html>
```

#### wsgi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    # Mimetype
    ctype = 'text/html'
    # File contents as body
    file_contents = [I NEED HELP HERE]
    response_body = b"<header>This is a header!</header>".join( \
        b"<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>".join( \
            file_contents.split(b"%(HEAD)") \
        ).split(b"%(HEADING)") \
    )

    # Heading
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [ \
        ('Content-Type', ctype), ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body))) \
    ]

    # Send response
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [response_body.encode('utf-8') ]
```

Now, I want to keep `main.html` separate from `wsgi.py`, but take the file contents of `main.html` and use it to create a dynamic webpage. I can not put `main.html` inside `wsgi.py` as a bytestring because I have *lots* of HTML, CSS, and JS files like this and I can not put that into all one file. Also, I can not make this a static file because it is not a static file, even though it is in this example. I am using Apache+mod_wsgi and hosting this on OpenShift with the Python 3.3 package. I am also using Github to deploy my app.

I'm assuming there's a way to do this because there must be someone else with the problem of separating their code into multiple files, but I couldn't find any solution after researching this on Google. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the files in your Github repository by looking at `environ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]`. This value is a string containing the file location of `wsgi.py` in the Github repository. Thus, `environ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"][:environ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"].rindex("/")]` is the directory of the Github repository and you can find all of your files from there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    # Mimetype
    ctype = 'text/html'

    # Directory
    dir = environ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"][:environ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"].rindex("/")]
    # Get File Contents
    file_contents = b""
    with open(dir+"/main.html", "rb") as file:
        file_contents = file.read()

    # Add Dynamic Content
    response_body = b"This is a header!".join( \
        b"".join( \
            file_contents.split(b"%(HEAD)") \
        ).split(b"%(HEADING)") \
    )

    # Heading
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [ \
        ('Content-Type', ctype), ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body))) \
    ]

    # Send Response
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [response_body.encode('utf-8') ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `wsgi.py`, it is just initial boilerplate code. If you create an application file in the wsgi folder, then `wsgi.py` will be ignored, and the Flask module defined in that application file will be run instead. Just create a file named `application` in `..\wsgi\` folder in root with the following contents (replace rafinder at the end with your own application name):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from rafinder import app as application
```

Now, create a Flask module named rafinder.py (or whatever you've defined) in that `wsgi` directory. All your static html/css files will now be referenced from this module. Your folder structure should look like this now:

```
wsgi.py
setup.py
.openshift/..
.settings/..
wsgi/..         => your python source files go here.
wsgi/application  => your application definition file.
wsgi/static..   => your static folders viz css, img, fonts, et al. go here.
```

Here is the sample module, `rafinder.py` that I've implemented in one of my apps. You can see some basic routing being used here:

```
import os
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import models

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/img'
# These are the extension that we are accepting to be uploaded
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

@app.route("/reset_database")
def reset_database():
    import_from_csv("wsgi/students.csv")
    return "Reset successful!"

@app.route("/")
def home():
    pass
```

Read my [entire article](http://blog.prahladyeri.com/2015/02/how-to-host-flask-app-openshift.html) to understand this in more detail.

Comment: I _really_ appreciate your answer and I hope it helps people using Flash, but I am not using Flask myself. I am just using Apache+mod_wsgi, so I just have a regular WSGI application and my solution has worked quite well. I hope both of our answers can help different people!

Comment: I don't think that Flask or not should matter in this case. I'd also started my openshift app as Apache+mod_wsgi, Flask is just a python library being used as a dependency. Even if you are not using Flask, the Application file still holds good. Only difference is, instead of the Flask module rafinder.py, you import your own wsgi compatible module (wsgi.py).

Comment: Well, I still think it's easier just to stick with the solution I have now because it still works and I would rather not move all of my files around. Do you think there are any disadvantages to my solution?

Comment: Sure you can. In that case, why can't you just import the code from main.html and display it in wsgi.py. You can do something like this: `file_contents = open('main.html', 'r')`

Comment: Also, in case your `main.html` is stored in your github folder, which is different than the path to `wsgi.py`, then you can get the repo path using `environ["OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"]` in your `wsgi.py` code.